# C Assigning pointers by derefrence or address operator

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

Is there a significant difference between these two methods for pointer assignment? `*pp = var` and `pp = &var`

Comment: Yes and it is explained in every C book. You really should read one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a **significant** difference:

- `*pp = var;` assigns the object `pp` points to with the value of `var`.
- `pp = &var;` assigns `pp` with the address of `var`, making it a pointer to variable `var`.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that if pp was uninitialized, `*pp = var` would make it point to var, the same as `pp = &var`.
I've been working my way through K & R, and pointers are completely new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say:

```
int a = 6;
int var = 7;
int *pp = &a;
```

then *pp = var means 'a' wil be 7 now.

```
pp = &var
```

means that pp is now pointing to 'var'.